# Troubleshooting advice: Can't view site locally, paths broken, site works fine live

Tags: php, less, local, filepath

Firstly, apologies if my question isn't appropriate for this forum, but I'm at a loose end and would really appreciate some tips to troubleshoot this issue. I have been trying for a while now but can't seem to work it out.

I have a functioning live site, that I helped put together  http://www.chrisdonaldson.com.au/
though my main contributions were css tweaks for style and typography, inclusion of all content but was not not really involved the backend development. This side of it was basically handled by another person who I cannot get help from any more.

My issue is that I **cannot get the site to view locally any more in order to make amendments**. That is, if I try to view an html page on a browser (firefox, chrome, safari etc) only the html text will come up, without any css formatting or any js functionality. It's obviously got something to do with the file paths, but since my last editions, I haven't changed anything in that regard and can't think of anything that would have changed on my own system (no change to users, permissions etc).

#### General information.

- I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and I'm the only user on this machine.
- I am able to view and develop other sites I am working on in the local environment.
- I was able to adjust the site's content about 1 month or so ago, with no problems viewing in the local environment.
- I have tried using firebug on the local files to see where things are breaking, but I don't know if I'm using firebug to it's full capacity, although I can at least tell that the css and js files are not being accessed.

#### Other information:

- The site uses css.less
- There is a php file that calls in a head.html and index.html, but I know anything about php, and maybe this is where things are going wrong? I can provide this code if required.

In terms of my own testing, I am simply downloading the site from it's live state, and without making any adjustments, trying to view locally. Basically I am passing html pages directly into the browser, or previewing via aptana studio, and the pages appear unformatted and without js functionality.

What I have noticed is that correcting a path, say from:
`<img src="/img/galleries/australiana/thumb/a_question_of_balance.jpg"/>`
to:
`<img src="../img/galleries/australiana/thumb/a_question_of_balance.jpg"/>`
will at least resolve the image path in question. **But why would this all of a sudden be an issue when it wasn't before? And the same tweaking for .less or .js files does not seem to resolve their paths.**

I realise that nobody will know exactly from the information I have provided what the problem is - but if it is appropriate to ask here, and someone is willing to help - what information should I provide so as to further attack the problem? This is mainly about troubleshooting, and if someone had some advice as to how to approach this, I'd really appreciate it.

Or is there another more appropriate place to seek advice?

Comment: It looks like the site was on the root of your local server but now it isn't.

Comment: Was working, now not. Something HAS changed no matter how much you say it hasn't.

Comment: He did not say it did not. The path obviously changed.

Comment: .. I haven't changed anything ... yes he did

Comment: Perhaps so @Dagon, but I really didn't think I did change anything. I had no reason to. But I will look into the paths and report back. Thanks for help and advice

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is relative and absolute paths to your images, css, and javascript files. When you transfer the site from your host to your local server you inherit all of the paths as well. An index.php OR index.html file with a link to"../path/to/img.jpg" actually means that whever the index.php/index.html file is, that it is accessing the image by backtracking one directory and going to /path/to/img.jpg.

It is simply a matter of fixing your relative and absolute paths.

Comment: Also agreed 100% with Mihai.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and feedback. Definitely something to do with the paths then. I guess my concerns were because it all worked fine before, and now it doesn't. I will look into the paths and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both relative and absolute paths in your website.
Lets say your website is on 'your_domain.com' in a folder called 'app'

In the file 'http://your_domain.com/app/index.html' when you say 
1) '/some_picture.png' means the picture found at http://your_domain.com/some_picture.png - it goes to the website domain (http://your_domain.com) and then it adds the path /some_picture.png

2) 'some_picture.png' means the picture found at http://your_domain.com/app/some_picture.png - it takes the current path (http://your_domain.com/app/) and it adds the file some_picture.png.

3) '../some_picture.png' means the picture found at http://your_domain.com/some_picture.png - it takes the current path (http://your_domain.com/app/) and it adds and it adds '../some_picture.png'. the '..' is the parrent directory so http://your_domain.com/ and it ads some_picture.png

What I suspect what you are doing is you want to access the website from a folder now (and not from the full domain like on your webhost). Instead of using local.webroot/yourdomain.com/ try defining local.yourdomain.com to get it working again.

Comment: Just create a local domain directly to the folder where your domain is. That will solve your problems. I do not know how to do that on Mac.

Comment: I would have to say that Mihai P. and Musa were closest to the mark as to the main issue I was having. For whatever reason I didn't have a localhost functioning properly anymore. After setting up MAMP and going through the steps to create a virtual host locally, all existing paths resolved correctly and the site worked locally. I will also try to outline some of the steps I went through in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem now solved

After installing MAMP I basically needed to set up a virtual-host and set up a new web root folder for the site in question. 
I followed the tutorial as found here http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php - there was no need for terminal in this tute, and was fairly easy to follow for a pleb like me.

Basically I added a virtual-host to the hosts file (Macintosh HD:private:etc:hosts) 
Then uncommented the line under 'Virtual hosts' #Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

And then, rather than editing the Applications:MAMP:con:apache:httpd.conf  file, as indicated by steps 6 onwards, I made these additions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"  ServerName localhost </VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80> "DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/mysitename" ServerName mysitename </VirtualHost>
```

to the /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file.

Anyway, basically now all paths resolve correctly, and I can set up new web roots for new jobs